# How to prove that the sequence $\{(n+1)/n\}$ is monotonic and bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> How to prove that the sequence $\{(n+1)/n\}$ is monotonic and bounded?

In order to do this I've been trying to show that $(n+1)/n$ is greater than $(n+2)/(n+1)$, but I've been having trouble actually proving it.

Comment: try  $\frac{n+1}{n} = 1 + \frac{1}{n}.$ use the fact  $\frac{1}{n}$ is decreasing and bounded above by 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{n+1}{n}=1+\frac{1}{n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\dfrac{n+1}{n} \geq  \dfrac{n+2}{n+1}$ since $(n+1)^2 - n(n+2) = 1 > 0$, this means $a_n = \dfrac{n+1}{n}$ is  decreasing  sequence. Further $a_n > 1, \forall n \geq 1$.

Comment: I guess I'm not catching it, how does exactly does this imply that it is an increasing sequence?

Comment: By multiplication of the inequality with $n$ and $n+1$ you get the above expression which is always true, because $(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n +1 \geq n^2 +2n = n (n+2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the inequality:
$$0 < 1$$
It follows that:
$$n < n+1$$
$$\frac{1}{n} > \frac{1}{n+1}$$
$$1 + \frac{1}{n} > 1 + \frac{1}{n+1}$$
$$\frac{n}{n} + \frac{1}{n} > \frac{n+1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+1}$$
$$\frac{n+1}{n} > \frac{n+2}{n+1}$$
This holds for all $n$.

It is clearly bounded above and below by 0 and 2.